# What are the things that “The Force Awakens” borrowed/parallel from “A New Hope?”

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, a-new-hope

The Internet is awash with criticisms (or is that praise) of how *Star Wars Episode VII: The Force Awakens* borrows, steals, homages, references, archetype-uses or parallels from *Star Wars Episode IV: A New Hope*.

What are those similarities?

Comment: I'll start the list and make it a CW so people can add.

Comment: Related question asks about things that directly appeared in both films (as opposed to being homages/parallels): http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111228/which-things-characters-do-the-force-awakens-and-a-new-hope-have-in-common

Comment: For prospective close voters: Note that *finite, answerable* list questions are generally considered on-topic and *not* too broad.

Comment: I'd suggest we open up to all of the Originals as their are parallels to all of them?

Comment: @JeremyFrench - I don't mind opening, but anything non-ANH should be explicitly marked so, the way I markd Vader's destroyed mask.

Comment: Wow you beat me by a day although my is about all Star Wars films and not just the A New Hope http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111440/previous-movie-story-line-references

Comment: [This article](http://www.ew.com/article/2015/12/19/star-wars-force-awakens-new-hope-similarities) lists eighteen points of similarity. I have added a few that were missing to the answer. I also like the summary in [this article](http://motherboard.vice.com/read/the-force-awakens-is-the-least-interesting-star-wars-yet) which begins "We watch imperial troops from a galactic empire pursue a robot with stolen plans across a desert planet..."

Comment: @joeytwiddle - awsome!!! Thanks!

Comment: Start with [The Hidden Fortress (1958)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0051808/), add a dash of [Chronicles of the Lensmen](http://www.amazon.com/Chronicles-Lensmen-Triplanetary-Lensman-Galactic/dp/1568658044) and garnish with [Flash Gordon (1936)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0027623/).

Answer (score 33):

In rough order of appearance, here's the list.  Note that a lot of these happen in a significantly different order between the two movies, so depending on which movie you're thinking of some things might seem out of place.

- The film starts with:

> a huge Star Destroyer moving slowly and ominously into view.

- The action starts on a desert planet:

> Tatooine vs. Jakku

- The young protagonist, who turns out to be very strong in the Force, has been left on the desert planet, lonely and dreaming of more, with no knowledge of his/her parents:

> Luke vs. Rey

- The protagonist meets a droid, frees it, and performs maintenance on it while they talk:

> Luke cleans R2 and removes his restraining bolt, Rey cuts BB-8 from a net and straightens his antenna.

- Said protagonist is subsequently forced to leave said desert planet

> in a spaceship called the *Millennium Falcon*.

- Stormtroopers in search of vital information they need:

> Plans of Death Star vs. Map to find Luke Skywalker

- Stormtroopers destroy innocent inhabitants in search of that vital information:

> Uncle Owen and Aunt Beru’s farm and Jawas vs. village of Tuanul

- Said information is hidden in a droid when the information carrier is about to fall into Imperial hands:

> Princess Organa hiding Star Wars plans in R2-D2 vs. Poe hiding the map in BB-8

- The one who had been carrying the information is captured by the Villain and tortured for their knowledge:

> Princess Organa being tortured by Vader for the location of the rebel base vs. Poe being tortured by Kylo Ren for the location of the map

- A stormtrooper takes off his helmet and says, "This is a rescue.":

> Luke Skywalker to Princess Leia in cell 2187 vs. Finn (FN-2187) to Poe Dameron

- The search for information is headed by the featured Villain of the film, who has a mask, heavy breathing, deep voice, follows the Dark Side of the Force, wears all black, and uses a red lightsaber:

> Darth Vader vs. Kylo Ren

- Said Villain holding someone off the floor by their neck:

> Vader and Captain Antilles vs. Kylo Ren and his subordinate

- There’s a real Big Bad hiding behind this villain:

> Emperor Palpatine/Darth Sidious vs. Supreme Leader Snoke

- There is a military commander with no force power but a similar rank, alongside the main villain:

> Governor / Grand Moff Tarkin vs. General Hux

- Han Solo is confronted over money-related issues and attempts to "talk his way out of it":

> Greedo (also Jabba) vs. the 2 groups of space pirates

- The *Millennium Falcon* is caught in a tractor beam and brought on board another vessel.  Those on board the *Falcon* attempt to evade capture by hiding in a compartment underneath the floor:

> Han, Chewie, Luke, and Obi-Wan (successful) vs. Rey, Finn, and BB-8 (unsuccessful)

- Han says, "I've got a bad feeling about this":

> In the trash compactor vs. when he is trapped by the two gangs

- Han talks about the Force, using flowery language:

> "Hokey religion" vs. "Mumbo-jumbo"

- The bad guys constructed a powerful weapon/base capable of destroying (an) entire planet(s):

> The Empire built the Death Star which destroys Alderaan vs. the First Order built Starkiller Base which destroys the Hosnian System

- A daring rescue is attempted from this base shortly before the final battle.

> Princess Leia vs. Rey

- The final battle of each movie results in the destruction of the aforementioned planet-destroying base, saving the day with mere moments to spare:

> Luke destroys the Death Star vs. Finn, Rey, Han and Chewie destroy the Starkiller Base

- The bad guys also do away with part of the galactic government:

> The Emperor dissolved the the Imperial Senate vs. Starkiller Base destroyed the capitol of the Republic on Hosnian Prime

- The protagonist is given Anakin Skywalker's lightsaber by a friend:

> Luke gets the lightsaber from Obi-Wan Kenobi vs. Rey gets it from Maz Kanata via Finn

- There is a cantina full of unique aliens and strangely-dressed humans, with strange music playing, where plans for transportation off planet are discussed:

> Mos Eisley vs. Takodana Castle

- One of the protagonists abandons the crusade out of desire for self-preservation (considered selfish), but later return to save a friend:

> Han and Chewbacca staying out of the Battle of Yavin until the last moment vs. Finn nearly running off with the two aliens from the tavern

- C-3PO has issues with his left arm

> His left arm was ripped off by Tusken Raiders (Sand People) in the first *Star Wars* film. In this film his left arm is red because it is a replacement arm due to circumstances that are not mentioned in the movie.

- Things with "Star" in their names:

> Death Stars and Star Destroyers vs. Starkiller Base

- A force user sneaks around a large cavernous room while unaware stormtroopers pass nearby, then pulls a lever:

> Obi-Wan on the Death Star vs. Rey on Starkiller Base

- The Villain and the newly reunited father figure / mentor share a pivotal scene while the other protagonists watch helplessly, and then scream:

> Darth Vader killing Obi-Wan vs. Kylo Ren killing Han Solo

- X-Wings must do a trench run over the giant superweapon.
- Political tensions between evil black-masked Force wielding villain, and military top brass:

> Vader and Motti vs. Kylo Ren and Hux

- Masked villain holding someone off the floor by their neck:

> Vader and Captain Antilles vs. Kylo Ren and his subordinate

- Someone is left for dead in a trash compactor:

> Leia, Han, Chewie, and Luke nearly die in a trash compactor vs. Captain Phasma gets sent (off-screen) to one

- A protagonist flies the Millennium Falcon while another protagonist shoots the gun and destroys TIE fighters, and gets cocky about it:

> Leia flying, Luke and Han shooting vs. Rey flying, Finn shooting

- The reclusive, wisened Jedi being sought after has prominent facial hair

> <strike>Gandalf vs. Dumbledore</strike>  Obi Wan Kenobi vs. Luke Skywalker.

- Despite the destruction of the super-weapon and the winning of the battle, we do not witness the death of the main villain.

> Darth Vader escaping in his Tie Fighter vs. Kylo Ren presumably being rescued by Hux at Snoke's request

- R2-D2 carries important secrets that aren't accessed until the end of the movie:

> R2 has the Death Star plans vs. R2 has part of the map to Luke Skywalker

- The wise old Jedi master finally returns, having previously disappeared after their student turned bad:

> Obi-Wan had disappeared to Tatooine after Anakin turned bad vs. Luke had disappeared after Ben Solo turned bad

Comment: Add both antagonistic sides of the movies building planet-destroying weapons/bases (Death Star and Starkiller whatever), and the final battle of each movie resulting in the destruction of those bases.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist - I made this CW specifically so the community can build the answer :) Edit away, Othello hast finished his work.

Comment: Also, if someone wants to improve the answer quality (link to examples, include examples, re-format, re-structure with types and subject etc...) go to town. This is meant to be The Very Definitive resource on the topic

Comment: @MrLister - that actually belongs on my second question (linked). But to answer your question, ALL details. That was the point of this Q&A

Comment: Gee, what a baby face! I can't believe the actor is actually in his thirties. Or was that part of the movie filmed years ago?

Comment: Daddy issues, nobody has mentioned daddy issues.

Comment: @JakeGould The question asks for similarities between Ep. IV and VII and *both* start with a Star Destroyer moving slowly and ominously into view. :)

Comment: @JakeGould You're right, and if the question was asking for similarities between Ep. V and VII then the launching of transport ships vs. probe droids would be a great thing to add to such a question. Basically even if other SW films also have something in common, if Ep. IV and VII have it in common then it goes with this question.

Comment: Two other things I think we're similar: 1) there was something wrong with the Millennium Falcon's motivator(?). 2) upon going to the weak spot of the death star/Starkiller they flew through a very similar trench

Comment: @IvoBeckers - please edit this in

Comment: How about both of the wise old Jedi (Obi Wan vs Luke) have prominent facial hair.

Comment: An orphan with latent Force skills ekes out a meager existence on a desert planet until teaming up with a swashbuckling rogue and an old man to return a droid with vital information to the freedom fighters. Along the way there's a cantina, the orphan's eyes are opened to the Force while using Anakin's lightsaber, the Big Bad strikes down the old man with a red lightsaber, the Senate is dissolved, and a single fighter blows up the immense spherical superweapon with a couple of well-aimed shots after said superweapon destroys an entire planet.

Comment: @MichaelItzoe I like your use of the word 'dissolved'.

Comment: @iMerchant - word it in a more archetypal way, and worth editing in :)

Comment: @JakeGould indeed I think *every* film starts with the credits crawl in space, then the camera twists to show a planet (or planetoid), then a ship appears, then a gigantic ship appears.