# Which things/characters do “The Force Awakens” and “A New Hope” have in common?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, a-new-hope

Related to this: [What are the things that “The Force Awakens” borrowed/parallel from “A New Hope?”](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111224/what-are-the-things-that-the-force-awakens-borrowed-parallel-from-a-new-hope/111225?noredirect=1#111225) (which asks which things the two films have in parallel/similarity):

Which things/characters do *The Force Awakens* and *A New Hope* have which appeared in both films?

You can include items from Episodes V/VI as well, *as long as they are explicitly marked as such*

### WARNING: The answer contains spoilers to *The Force Awakens*!

*To clarify: This question is specific to items which are actually in-universe the same item in both films. It does NOT include items that are of the same kind/type but in-universe are different items - in other words, two droids or ships of the same type that aren't explicitly the same exact droid/ship are **offtopic***
.

Comment: As with another question, I'll start the list and make it CW so people can perfect it

Comment: For prospective close voters: Note that *finite, answerable* list questions are generally considered on-topic and *not* too broad.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the things that “The Force Awakens” borrowed/parallel from “A New Hope?”](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111224/what-are-the-things-that-the-force-awakens-borrowed-parallel-from-a-new-hope)

Comment: @NominSim - **how so**? 90%+ of the things that belong on an answer here don't belong there, and vice versa. This one asks about **exact same** items (explicitly **not** types of items), the other one mostly asks about themes/ideas.

Answer (score 12):

This is a second answer, which lists specifically things that aren't simply *parallel/borrowed*, but actually **were in both films**.

- **Characters**

  - Chewbacca
  - Han Solo
  - Leia Organa
  - C-3PO
  - R2-D2
  - Luke Skywalker
  - [Obi Wan Kenobi](https://www.ew.com/article/2015/12/20/jj-abrams-reveals-obi-wan-and-yoda-are-star-wars-force-awakens) (voice only)
  - [Yoda](https://www.ew.com/article/2015/12/20/jj-abrams-reveals-obi-wan-and-yoda-are-star-wars-force-awakens) (voice only)  (NOT in ANH, Ep5/6 only)
  - Admiral Ackbar (NOT in ANH, Ep6 only)
  - Nien Nunb  (NOT in ANH, Ep6 only)
- **Vehicles**

  - Millenium Falcon
- **Objects**

  - Darth Vader's melted mask (only melted from Episode VI)
  - Luke Skywalker's (originally Anakin's) lightsaber
  - The [Dejarik](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Dejarik) game (aka: “Hologram Board Game”) on the Millennium Falcon
  - The [Remote](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Remote) Luke used on the  Millennium Falcon (possibly the same)
  - Chewbacca’s [Bowcaster](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Bowcaster) (possibly the same)
  - Han Solo’s [DL-44 heavy blaster pistol](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/DL-44_heavy_blaster_pistol) (possibly the same)
- **Planets/Locations**

  - Several planets are mentioned on a Galactic map which are known from OT, *assuming that map is identical to one published in Visual Dictionary*. I'll include the actual list later, when we can get high-res HD still from the film to confirm they are included, but E.g. Dantooine seems to be on both. Tatooine as well.
- **Phrases**

  - Millennium Falcon doing Kessel run in 12 Parsecs
  - "I've got a bad feeling about this" by Han
  - "Use the Force"
  - "May the Force be with you"
  - "piece of junk" (of the Millennium Falcon)

Comment: @MrLister - didn't want to do ALL the work :)

Comment: Oh, OK. This answer wasn't CW, so I wasn't sure I could...

Comment: For vehicles, wouldn't TIE Fighter and X-Wing Fighter count, or do we consider the newer incarnations of them to be too disparate from the original versions?

Comment: I think the idea is the same vehicles, not the same kind of vehicles.

Comment: @vynsane - what Mr. Lister said. Same vehicles, not same types.

Comment: @MrLister - sorry, forgot to click CW checkbox. Fixed

Comment: I'm pretty sure someone 'had a bad feeling about this'

Comment: Can we add "The Force" to this list? Is it a thing, a being, an object?

Comment: ALL - please stop adding same TYPES of things. The TIE fighters and Star Destroyers and X-Wing helmets aren't **the same** items in both films, they are same **types** of items. Question doesn't cover that (and they are largely meaningless)

Comment: are we counting the *crashed* star destroyer(s), x-wings, and TIE fighters? Because they *are* the same as in Ep. IV

Comment: @RedCaio - do you have canon proof that the actual crashed X-Wing we see in E4 is the SAME EXACT X-Wing from E7? Despite being on 2 diffferent planets?

Comment: @JakeGould - I was being fascetious (sp?). We know that the crashed Star Destroyer on Jakku is extremely unlikely to have been any of the Star Destroyers in OT (because there were 100s of them). There was only one known Vader's mask, and canon strongly implies this one is authentic.

Comment: @Mooz - the Force in OT never took naps it needed to awake from. I call shenanigans and claim it's NOT the same "Force" :) I wouldn't object to it being added too much but it kinda sounds *meh* to me as part of an answer

Comment: @JakeGould - I'd ask on main site first if it's the same chest?

Comment: @JakeGould - that said, if they are NOT the same chest, that would be a good item to add to my counterpart Q&A about things borrowed from ANH. A chest where a lightsaber is stored seems like one.

Comment: I don't see Coursant listed. That was the planet that was annihilated, right? And also didn't see the "Jedi mind trick" listed either.

Comment: @imer no it wasnt. Jedi mind trick yes

Comment: Yoda & Obi Wan (voice only) were in TFA during the flashbacks/visions Rey saw when she picked up Luke's lightsaber.

Comment: @iMerchant - is that confirmed for sure?

Comment: Yes. From the lips of JJ himself in an interview with Entertainment Weekly. They even brought in Ewan McGregor and Frank Oz to record the lines. http://www.ew.com/article/2015/12/20/jj-abrams-reveals-obi-wan-and-yoda-are-star-wars-force-awakens

Comment: @iMerchant - then definitely please edit that in! Preferably with links to the proof

Comment: @DVK - I added Yoda & Obi Wan as well as Jedi mind trick to the list. BTW, what planet was nuked on TFA if not Courusant? They said they were taking out the Republic/Senate leadership, heart of the Republic, or something to that effect. Did all that move to a different planet, which was subsequently vaporized?

Comment: @iMerchant - it was covered in another Q&A here. It was New Republic's Senate's temporary capital planet

Comment: @ALL - **Please **stop adding things that are "same generic type" of thing** to this answer. It is only for **same exact object**. "R2D2" counts, but a "mouse-type droid" **does not**. Millenium Falcon counts, but generic "TIE-fighters" do not.

Comment: Yoda was definitely NOT in A New Hope. Unless Lucas added it while I was not looking.

Comment: @DiegoSánchez - I re-added them to the answer, but very explicitly marked as "not in ANH". Great catch, thanks!

Comment: Is Han's belt part of Han Solo or can we consider it a separate entity?