# What are the parallels between The Force Awakens and previous Lucas films (excluding Episode IV)?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

Everyone has their own opinions but to me *Star Wars: The Force Awakens* felt like it was previous movies stitched together.

How many scenes are essential copy cat ideas of previous films (excluding A New Hope)?

Possible scenes

> The Millenium Falcon being sucked up and Rey and Finn hiding under the bridge (same as Luke and Han Solo), the BB-8 essentially having secret information (R2-D2 & C3P-O had similar information), and the death planet being blown up (similar to the Death Star).

[This](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111224/what-are-the-things-that-the-force-awakens-borrowed-parallel-from-a-new-hope) is rather similar although I am explicitly excluding "A New Hope" so it should be different.

Comment: @randal'thor Yes I added that to the end of the post although I would like to include all movies and not just "A New Hope"

Comment: @William - you can rephrase your question to explicitly exclude A new Hope.

Comment: I think you could probably pick apart every scene of the movie and find something from the other 6 that matches up in some way, based on anyone's opinion. I think the scope needs to be tightened up, and maybe just ask about Easter Eggs type head-nods, instead of being a free-for-all.

Comment: Sorry this got closed as a dupe, I thought I'd retracted my vote after the edit to exclude ANH.

Comment: @CreationEdge I'm rather surprised this was closed considering I was quit explicit that I was excluding "A New Hope."  Do you think I should delete this and ask another because I can't even cast to reopen question because rep is so low.

Comment: Maybe we can see if someone like @DVK can help out, because it's clear this isn't a dupe of the linked question. My close vote was meant to be retracted, as it was cast pre-edit.

Comment: @CreationEdge - oups. I accidentally VTROed when the question didn't yet have star-wars tag so it wasn't binding :(   You need to round up one more VTRO on chat

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To say the film is a patchwork or rehash of old ideas is to misunderstand the very nature of the narrative style employed in the overall scope of the main series to begin with. Rooted in eastern mysticism: its cyclical. The same themes, ideas, etc...will always be at play

Certainly most of the comparisons will be with A New Hope because this is the first film in the new trilogy - however,

- The lightsaber stuck in the snow recalls Empire Strikes Back
- Snoke/Ren holographic conversations evoke Empire Strikes Back
- Han and Leia's musical motif is from Empire Strikes Back
- The final battle is more Return of the Jedi than New Hope due to

  > a ground team needed to lower shields, bunker explosions, and a lone ship diving into the heart of the mechanism to deliver the final blow

Comment: The visual design of the resistance base alone evokes Yavin, Hoth and Home One all at once.

Comment: I would recommend making this CW so the community can build the list (your call)

Comment: @DVK - I am unfamiliar with "CW" - I suspect you have the powers to do that though so if you think it would be beneficial, please feel free.

Comment: @NathanK.Campbell - Community Wiki. It's hugely controvercial, and I would never **impose** it on anyone (leaving aside the fact that only original poster or moderator can do that, by clicking "CW" checkbox when editing your question). I wouldn't even pressure anyone into making their answer CW. The main implications for you are that (1) you no longer gain any reputation from your post even if upvoted - the post is now owned by user "community"; (2) People can't complain that you posted a "list" answer just to gain rep. Which may or may not matter to you :)

Comment: The only reason I even recommended it is that I have done so with 2 of my answers that are similar to this post, and I like neat patterns :)))

Comment: Maz was fairly Yoda-like (small enigmatic alien who knows more than they're letting on).

Comment: Pretty big ESB parrallel - second-in-command dark-side bady guy turns out to have a father-son relationship with one of the good guys (or turns out to be related to Luke).