# What's the relationship between the Resistance and the Republic?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

As far as I understand it in TFA we have three major political forces:

- The New Republic
- The First Order
- The Resistance

Do we know -- is The Resistance *part of* the Republic, just the part that is engaging in the fight against The First Order? Or is the Resistance adjacent to the Republic somehow?

Comment: The First Order and the Republic are both nations.  Each has their own territory.  The Resistance is a guerilla organization operating in First Order territory, with the covert assistance of the Republic.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The Visual Dictionary covers that:

It is NOT part of the Republic officially. It's a private organization run by General Organa.

[image]

Comment: why do half of the statemnets remind me of the senate in episode 1?

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, and also fits Leia's personality.  "Would it help if I got out and pushed?" -- apparently she did!

Comment: @Thomas - because that's pretty much how all democratic governments end up behaving. Art imitating life. Churchill was entirely too right :)

Comment: That must be why it's entire military force consists of an X-Wing squadron lol

Comment: @Thomas the number of parallels and role reversals between the episodes can be rather interesting to point out.

Comment: @MichaelT - http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111224/what-are-the-things-that-the-force-awakens-borrowed-parallel-from-a-new-hope

Comment: For real-life parallels of private/volunteer armies fighting fascistic powers, loosely supported by governments reluctant to get their hands dirty, consider the [International Brigades](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Brigades) in the Spanish Civil War, or the Kurdish [Peshmerga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peshmerga), the [Free Syrian Army](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_Syrian_Army) and various others fighting ISIS and others in Iraq and Syria, or countless [armies in proxy wars in the Cold War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_proxy_wars#Cold_War_proxy_wars).

Comment: Didn't the resistance exist before Leia though? I don't think she created it

Comment: @DavidGrinberg - It sounds to me that the "Resistance" is a rogue false flag operation by General Leia Solo, with the name referring to "locals resisting" the First Order's growing influence. There are other ways to interpret this, though, especially if real locals are actually involved.

Comment: I don't understand....is the the First Order not part of the Republic? What is the territory of the Republic and First Order relative to the Empire? 20 years earlier the Rebels were on full whoop ass mode with the Empire. Where/when did that stop?

Comment: @Paul Draper The Rebellion won enough to reestablish itself as the New Republic but the Empire was never 100% defeated.  The First Order started as an Imperial Remnant.

Answer (score -1):

My guess is that the Resistance is part of the New Republic, but it's a separate sect run by General Leia Organa. It probably was created by the New Republic to defend against the Empires Followers, aka The First Order, while TNR rebuilt its political/economical stance in a galaxy far far away. :)