# Further clarification on the relationship & territorial dynamics between the First Order, New Republic and the Resistance

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

Does the Resistance strike at Imperial territories from Republic space or does it operate from directly within Imperial space Rebellion-style?

Comment: Not sure what this is asking that isn't answered in the image provided by the accepted answer in the linked question. Questions about further clarification of an answer should be posted as a comment on the existing post.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the relationship between the Resistance and the Republic?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111579/whats-the-relationship-between-the-resistance-and-the-republic)

Comment: @TylerH Pretty sure the OP is now asking about information on the Empire/First Order, and the accepted answer to the other question gives information only about the Resistance.  Perhaps the last paragraph should be removed for clarity.

Comment: @DaveJohnson Ah, I missed the question in the middle paragraph; I assumed the last paragraph was the only question block. I agree, it should be edited out if this question is to remain open.

Comment: I posted an answer relating to the last paragraph ("does the Resistance operate from Imperial space"). If not too much trouble, please delete out the other 2  independent questiosn that are contained here ("whether First order is one of the warlord factions or the last one" is a great question which should be asked separately, as is " is the Resistance considered a splinter group that broke away from the Republic" - to which I do have an asnwer)

Answer (score 1):

According to novelization (quotes TBP), the Resistance is NOT operating from First Order territory.

When Snoke discusses firing Starkiller weapon at the Resistance planet, they explicitly discusss with General Hux the merits of **taking out just the base planet, and *adding* the rest of the planets in that star system to First Order control *after that***.

Comment: Add-on: I'm waiting to answer this when it's posted as a separate question, but the answer to " is the Resistance considered a splinter group that broke away from the Republic" - not quite. Snoke considers them a separate entity but one **fully backed** by the Republic (which we know isn't the actual case).