# The Force Awakens Easter Eggs?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

What are the known Easter eggs in The Force Awakens?

Note: Due to community input, Easter Eggs **should be** limited to references of the previous Star Wars films, **and are meant/confirmed by the writers/directors/etc. to be Easter Eggs**. Also, please be aware that this can lead to **spoilers**.

Comment: I don’t think it’s a dupe, but it feels like it might be straying into “too broad” territory.

Comment: I actually think the other 2 questions should probably be a dupe of *this* one.

Comment: I understand it may be too broad. How could it be reworded to fit the requirements of this site?

Comment: Answer: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=shT0797BkpY

Comment: @CreationEdge does that only cover what is shown in the trailers? Seems like it might be to me.

Comment: I changed the link. The first one was just the trailer, yes. (I pulled the wrong one from my browser history). Updated with a new one!

Comment: @CreationEdge ahh now that's a great source. Can it be made into a proper answer for this site? I know that I always love to know about the Easter Eggs in movies and being able to search for them on SE would be great.

Comment: I'm leaning towards this one being too opinion-based; it's going to be hard to know if a specific item in the movie was *intended* to be an Easter Egg or we're just overthinking it.

Comment: @MikeEdenfield I wonder if I asked this question too early after the film's release.

Comment: @MikeEdenfield JJ et al have done a lot of interviews clarifying some of those things, so I think it's entirely possible we can get a clear idea of confirmed Easter Eggs. For instance: http://www.ew.com/article/2015/12/20/jj-abrams-reveals-obi-wan-and-yoda-are-star-wars-force-awakens I expect as time goes on we'll get more evidence.

Comment: Why is this close but the other similar questions still open? http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111224/what-are-the-things-that-the-force-awakens-borrowed-parallel-from-a-new-hope

Comment: @CreationEdge They're not similar; those can be quantified. Compare a scene X in *A New Hope* versus scene Y in *The Force Awakens*: we can tell whether they are similar or not based on the contents of the scene (i.e. Trash compactor in both movies); whereas how do we **know for sure** that a particular scene or character is an Easter Egg? Did the producers tell us? do we *think* it's an Easter Egg?

Comment: @Mooz As I commented above, yes, the producers *do* tell us this stuff. It's like this was closed because it was asked too early, not because it's not answerable.

Comment: @CreationEdge That's my point, the OP hasn't specified whether they want our opinions, or whether an Easter Egg is confirmed by the producers or not.

Comment: @Mooz There's a meta discussion on this and similar questions right now, too. But if the OP doesn't roll back my edit, then we've narrowed the scope a bit.

Comment: I would say that it must be confirmed and not just opinion. I will make an edit to the question to specify this.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here you go. Easter Eggs, Cameos, and References.

*This list has been expanded to include more than just the reference video.*

**New Hope parallels**

- Person stranded on a desert planet destined for more
- Opening scene with storm troopers killing rebels
- Mind tricks and hiding on a large base
- Stormtrooper dressed as a rebel vs rebel dressed as Stormtrooper
- Han Solo "I have a bad feeling about this"
- Trash compactor
- Anakin's lightsaber being stored in Obi-Wan's chest
- Feeling a death from across the galaxy (Leia and Obi-Wan)
- Trench run
- Millenium Falcon

  - 12 parsecs
  - Floor compartments
  - Board game
  - Jedi training device

**Other Film References**

- Millennium Falcon has a new square dish, which replaced the round one lost in RotJ. (Also as mentioned in Heir to the Empire)
- Pulling lightsabers out of snow with the force (ESB)
- Someone falling to their death from a great height (ESB, RotJ)
- Killing monster with a door (RotJ)
- Must drop the shields for the attack to begin (RotJ)
- Pod racers (TPM)

**Recurring themes**

- Limb loss - in that C3PO has a new arm
- Facial scars
- Jedis in exile

**Recurring Non-central Characters / Ships**

- Admiral Akbar
- Nien Nunb
- Clone troopers (mentioned)
- Old style X-Wing, Tie-fighter, and Star Destroyer ship wreckage on Jakku

**Random References**

- Pilot Ello Asty is a reference to Beastie Boys song Hello Nasty and written in Aurebesh on his helmet: "Born to Ill"
- Various voice actors from previous Star Wars cartoons and games
- Various characters and locations named after people related to JJ Abrams or other production crew.

  - Poe Dameron is named after Abram's daughter's toy polar bear and his assistant.
  - Abrams' father plays a resistance officer Captain Cypress
  - Abram's grandfather is references as a Kelvin Ridge
- Michael Giacchino as a Stormtrooper
- Daniel Craig as a Stormtrooper (interacting with Rey)
- Simon Pegg as Unkar Plutt
- Onscreen appearance of [R2KT](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/R2-KT)

Comment: new dish on the falcon isn't a new hope parallel

Comment: With the list of references so long, I was surprised nobody hit their head while going through a door ...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Are you referring to a missed referenced?

Comment: "Anakin's lightsaber being stored in Obi-Wan's chest" I read this quite wrong the first time I thought about it